# How do I start a command only if cpu load isn't too high

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7, batch-processing

I know the command for displaying the current cpu usage:

```
C:\>wmic cpu get loadpercentage
LoadPercentage
91
```

Now I would like to have a command which waits until the cpu load falls under 80%, for example. Ideally only if it falls below that threshold for 2 seconds or so.

In the end I want to spawn a new sub-process (exe-file) in a for-loop with a list of arguments. It's a single thread application, so on 4 cores it should automatically spawn 4 times and add a new one as soon as one of them stops utilizing the cpu (it doesn't exit).

Example for the loop with fixed 2 seconds waiting:

```
c:\>for /D %a IN (A B C D E) DO timeout 2 & start my.exe %a
```

Comment: you could try to launch it from Performance Monitor as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414.aspx (please scroll down to comments for discussion how to run a script/batch)

Comment: @wmz that's interesting, thanks. I just have no practical idea how to let that alert run the command each time with the next parameter from the list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "process=calc.exe"
    set "levelToStart=80"
    set "startHits=2"
    set "normalWaitTime=5"
    set "testWaitTime=1"

    set "lowLevelHits=0"
    set "waitTime=%normalWaitTime%"

    for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K) do (
        call :waitForCPU
        echo start "" "%process%" %%a
    )

    endlocal
    exit /b 

:waitForCPU
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%y in (
        'wmic cpu get loadpercentage /value'
    ) do set /a "cpu=%%y"
    if %cpu% lss %levelToStart% ( 
        set /a "lowLevelHits+=1"
        set "waitTime=%testWaitTime%"
    )
    if %lowLevelHits% gtr %startHits% (
        set "lowLevelHits=0"
        set "waitTime=%normalWaitTime%"
        exit /b
    )
    timeout %waitTime% >nul 
    goto waitForCPU
```

Comment: Great, that looks very good (if you remove the "echo", you forgot ;-) ) - testing...

Comment: @maf-soft, the `echo` was deliberate for testing. What i forget was to document i included it.

Comment: It works great out of the box, thanks a lot!
(I would say, things included just for testing should not be in the published listing, even if you document it...)

Comment: @maf-soft, as systems are not always equally configured, just to prevent problems, we usually include the `echo` before the commands that can "hurt" or interfere. That is the reason for the `echo` before the command starting in this case, or before a `rd` or a `del` .... If the output to console is OK, then the echo can be removed. But i SHOULD have included the explanation.